# Did Debian lenny repositories vanish?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, http-status-code-404

Today, I tried to install packages through `apt-get`, but I encountered a lot of 404 errors. My `sources.list` was fully working last Friday (no changes to my knowledge), now I get:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.230.54.99 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/main/source/Sources  404 Not Found [IP: 130.230.54.99 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/main/source/Sources  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
```

When I browse for example http://security.debian.org/dists/ there seems to be no lenny directory. What's the issue?

Comment: Ok, it seems that lenny is moved to archieve. No suprise as it's passed already EOF: http://wiki.debian.org/DebianLenny

Comment: Noticed the same just lately a and decided to move on. Will take me a night or so, but still better this way. The machine should have been better maintained in the first place :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Since

- Lenny is EOLed
- lenny security updates have been terminated on February 6th
- lenny backports have been dicontinued on March 25th
- lenny volatile has been discontinued with the release of its successor "squeeze"

the repositories have been moved to archive.debian.org - you may wish to update your repositories to match this:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
# Volatile:
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
# Backports:
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free
# Previously announced security updates:
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main
```

Comment: You saved my life and sanity with that answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i've got `W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/volatile Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFD993306D849617
`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to

```
gpg  --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net  --recv-keys DFD993306D849617
```

to avoid the "NO_PUBKEY" error.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me - this worked:

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.PREARCHIVE
```

From http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=95658, make new `/etc/apt/sources.list` with

```
# SOURCE: http://superuser.com/questions/404806/did-debian-lenny-repositories-vanish
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports-sloppy main
```

Then

```
gpg  --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net  --recv-keys DFD993306D849617
apt-get update
```

Comment: `gpg` needs some funny port number to request keys. How annoying. Why don't the use port 80.

Answer (score 0):

For people who like me are searching for a place to download individual packages for the Debian 5 Lenny the best option as of now is [archive.debian.net](http://archive.debian.net/)